# javascript - how to control setinterval internal

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my application development, I am using

```
setInterval(function() {
  // some code
  // runs here
}, 60000);
```

I want to execute some code on 1 minute interval and my code may take 2-3 minutes in some cases.

```
<execute code> - <wait 1 minute> - <execute code> - <wait 1 minute> ......so on
```

I tried with setInterval function but noticed that setInterval does not wait for inner code to complete. Please suggest how can i achieve this in javascript.

Thanks

Comment: *I want to execute some code on 1 minute interval and my code may take 2-3 minutes* So 1 min interval or 2 or 3?

Comment: If your code might take longer than the interval, then `setTimeout` might be a better option so you not start the next iteration before the first has completed.

Comment: Why does your code takes so much time do you have promises in it ?

Comment: Some warnings: if your code needs to do something at 1 minute intervals, you *really* don't want to rely on `setInteverl` or `setTimeout` becuase your users will lose interest and move on to different tabs and that will _heavily_ deprioritize your tab and cause your interval basically be completely invalidated. What do you *actually* want to do? I.e. the interval is a means to an end, what actually _happens_ once a minute? Is the one minute mark important? Because it probably isn't: what should your user(s) see when they come back to your tab?

Comment: I am calculating summary data from raw and want to show on dashboard page. 1 minute i am putting as wait time between consecutive iterations else system may crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way may be to recursively call your job function with `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function jobThatRunEveryMinute() {
  // run code here that may take more than one minute
  someExpensiveCodeToRun()

  // start another job after someExpensiveCode completes
  setTimeout(jobThatRunEveryMinute, 60000);
}, 60000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work for you, but why do you have a function that takes over 1 min to return something?

```
let callCompleted = true;

setInterval(function() {
   if (callCompleted) {
      callCompleted = false;

      // pass a call back function to update the callCompleted to true
      myLongRunningFunction(function() { callCompleted = true } );

      // or if `myLongRunningFunction` returns a promise 
      myLongRunningFunction.then(() => { callCompleted = true } );
   } 
}, 60000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// adjust wait time to your liking
const waitTime = 10000 
let time = 0
// so you can stop it
const totalTime = 6 

function excuteCode() {
  time++;
  console.log(time);  // <=== replace with your inner code
  if (time < totalTime) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      excuteCode()
    }, waitTime)
  }
}

excuteCode();
```